# Extract command line arguments from eclipse Run Configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jar, command-line-arguments

I am trying to build my java project using Ant script, however I would like to extract all the

command line arguments eclipse uses for compiling my source code and creating a jar file as well.
Is there anyway to find these arguments out instead of reading the whole 'javac' and 'jar' manuals?

By the way, I am new to Ant and not an expert in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try File -> Export -> General -> Ant Buildfiles. Works for most Java projects. You will get a ready to use ant script based on your Eclipse project metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Use ant tasks to compile your program and create a jar instead.   Here is a good ant tutorial: 
http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html